# How do I loop through two arrays and to return a single array with values in order?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is a stupid question but I am having such a hard time figuring this out.

Let's say I have two arrays:

```
let a = ["I", "a"]
let b = ["have", "cat"]
```

and I want to loop through them both so that my output would be a single array that becomes:

```
let c = ["I", "have", "a", "cat"]
```

I tried to do a nested for loop however, I am getting a bunch of weird errors. I was also trying forEach but I get an error message saying my array is undefined... so not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

One quick method is to map array `a` to, thus:

```
[a1,a2] ===> [[a1,b1], [a2,b2]]
```

And the flatten the resulting array to produce:

```
[a1,b1,a2,b2]
```

**DEMO**

```js
let a = ["I", "a"]
let b = ["have", "cat"]
let c = [].concat(...a.map((e,i) => [e, b[i]]));
console.log( c ); // ["I", "have", "a", "cat"]
```

Comment: Thank you! This was able to solve my issue. However, can you explain why you used the spread operator for the a array? I am having a tough time understanding why the spread operator essentially flattens the array and saves us a step

Comment: The spread operator changed `[[a1,b1], [a2,b2]]` to `[a1,b1,a2,b2]`, basically flattening the array of arrays. There are several approaches to flattening an array; this is just one of the many.